# image only showing inside of the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has inside an image. However if the image is bigger than div, it will fill  outside of the div. What i want is a mask basically.

So the image should be visible inside the limits of the div. background-image is not an option. How can be solved?

```
<div style="height:400px; width:400px; background-color:red">
    <img src="xxx.jpeg"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pJC5e/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `overflow: hidden` I guess ?

```
<div style="height:400px; width:400px; background-color:red; overflow: hidden">
    <img src="xxx.jpeg"/>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pJC5e/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the parent container a `overflow: hidden` rule. This will cut off the image inside when it reaches the parent's boundaries.